# VBA code to find and highlight a combination of characters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a VBA code in Word to highlight any sentence that has a period outside the quotation mark. i.e. In the text "Hello word". i want " and . to be highlighted when running the macro.

@il_raffa.. I have a code with me to highlight words that i don't want to see in the letter. Have no idea about how to incorporate symbols in it.

```
    Sub HighlightTargets2()

    Dim range As range
   Dim i As Long
   Dim TargetList

   TargetList = Array("I", "We", "our", "discusses about", "we", "asserts")
   For i = 0 To UBound(TargetList)

   Set range = ActiveDocument.range

   With range.Find
   .Text = TargetList(i)
   .Format = True
   .MatchCase = False
   .MatchWholeWord = True
   .MatchWildcards = True
   .MatchSoundsLike = False
   .MatchAllWordForms = False

   Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
   range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

   Loop

   End With
   Next

   End Sub
```

Comment: Did you make any attempt to do it?

Comment: @il_raffa.. I have code with me to highlight word that i don't want to see in the letter. Here it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found before that Word uses a Smart Quote so if you just use " is wont work

Just add the following, above your TargetList line of code

```
'Chr(148) is the Character Code for Word Smart quote
'This is what is inserted into Word when you press "
char1 = Chr(148) & "."
```

And change your TargetList:

```
TargetList = Array("I", "We", "our", "discusses about", "we", "asserts", char1)
```

Have tried and it worked to Highlight the ".

Answer (score 0):

In Word, display the Find dialog box. (Ctrl+F displays the task pane instead of the dialog box, choose "Advanced" from the dropdown list.)

Type ". in the Find box then click "Reading Highlight", then "Highlight all".

If you really need this in a macro, record a macro then perform the actions described above.

Comment: I would prefer using codes because there are many words and symbols that my clients wouldn't want to see it in the letter. We have been trying this Find & Replace option. It didn't work out as we missed many words. So I am trying to create a code which would highlight all these words. Autocorrect would not be an option as we mostly do a copy paste job. Please can u suggest a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: please explain how using find did not work for the combination you mentioned in your original question. I did test before making the suggestion. And i explained how to make the macro code.

Comment: We have so many words and symbols to check. So using find for each and every word or symbol would take take more of our time. I tried using macro. Did not work for me. I did it exactly as you said. Created a macro, did find and reading highlight for all words and symbols that i wanted to highlight, and stopped recording. But it didnt work. However i just tried to bold a word by just using the keyboard. it worked. Is it because i used mouse action that it didn't work for me